# Can anyone help me find this old RPG system using books to battle?

Tags: product-identification, books

This is probably from the 80s at some point - each player had a book that represented their character - so your book could have been a dragon, or a goblin. As I recall, each player picked an attack from their book, and then the results were compared to determine the effects and how much damage each player took. It was merely a duel game using books. Does anyone recall this?

Comment: There's something similar in the Zatch Bell card game.  Rather than having "decks" of cards, you construct your spellbook in the exact order you want, so that typically you have two choices of cards to use (each "page" holds one card on front and one on back, so with the book open you have two facing pages of cards) - and damage taken can cause you to flip pages and can throw off your carefully constructed plan.  It's not an RPG - despite you ostensibly taking on the role of the fighters' human partners - but it sounds like its in the same genre as the Combat Books.

Answer (score 11):

Answering my own question after having furiously googled for 15 additional minutes. Lost Worlds Fantasy Combat Books.

Comment: As I recall, this was an offshoot of a WWI air combat book set that worked the same.  Not sure I'd call it an RPG, though.

Comment: It was! Ace of Aces! Agree that it's little more than a combat system.